# .env for prod and developpment with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, environment-variables

I saw lot of different ways, some looked normal some others looked a bit more patchworked.

Can we use package json script to chose our env variables ? What is the right way to do it with nodeJS and how to do it ?

I have already made an **.env**. It contains api keys which are global for dev and prod. But I have some variables, the `URL` variable for exemple, which won't be the same depending on dev or prod.

Here are my scripts in the `package.json`

```
      ...
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "nodemon app.js",
        "prod": "node app.js"
      }
```

Comment: I personally prefer not to attach and maintain extra libraries for some trivial tasks that can be achieved with few lines of code and reading key/value pairs from .env file seems to me fairly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `cross-env` package to define a NODE_ENV for the command you are running. e.g. "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node app.js"
2. In the code, read the env file based on the `NODE_ENV` config. FWIW `dotenv` package can help with reading `.env` files.

Comment: Just a quick note: `cross-env` is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env/issues/257)

Comment: Thank you both, if cross-env is no longer maintained I guess it's better looking for something else

Comment: Well nope, you should use it. It is a reliable tool. The only reason it is not maintained is that the developer won't add new features, but the package does its purpose like a charm, so no worries.